# OpenStreetMap binding between a node and relation

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

For example, I have this node:

```
<node id="1159592166" version="2" timestamp="2014-06-20T14:18:34Z" uid="1942179" user="CzechAddress" changeset="23044606" lat="50.0121501" lon="15.9559037">
    <tag k="addr:conscriptionnumber" v="46"/>
    <tag k="addr:country" v="CZ"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="46"/>
    <tag k="addr:place" v="Platěnice"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="53002"/>
    <tag k="ref:ruian:addr" v="7567138"/>
</node>
```

And this relation:

```
<relation id="436721" version="28" timestamp="2018-03-12T20:22:00Z" uid="787799" user="czechreg" changeset="57123511">
    <member type="node" ref="1585113507" role="admin_centre"/>
    <member type="relation" ref="429108" role="subarea"/>
    <member type="relation" ref="429333" role="subarea"/>
    <member type="relation" ref="429786" role="subarea"/>
    <member type="relation" ref="429109" role="subarea"/>
    <member type="relation" ref="435471" role="subarea"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179382288" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179456283" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179456430" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179456429" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179456428" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179456432" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179633268" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179641571" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179910070" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179910323" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179910320" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179910319" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179910325" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="179913217" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="180639038" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="180639036" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="180639051" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="181680255" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="181852616" role="outer"/>
    <member type="way" ref="240282766" role="outer"/>
    <tag k="admin_level" v="8"/>
    <tag k="boundary" v="administrative"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Moravany"/>
    <tag k="name:cs" v="Moravany"/>
    <tag k="name:prefix" v="obec"/>
    <tag k="population" v="1795"/>
    <tag k="ref" v="CZ0532575399"/>
    <tag k="source" v="cuzk:ruian"/>
    <tag k="source:population" v="csu:rso"/>
    <tag k="type" v="boundary"/>
    <tag k="wikidata" v="Q2521236"/>
    <tag k="wikipedia" v="cs:Moravany (okres Pardubice)"/>
  </relation>
```

If I search this place in nominatim [here](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/details.html?osmtype=N&osmid=1159592166&class=place), I see relation 436721 under the address.

Where do I find the binding between a node element and a relation in xml extracted by osmosis?

Answer (score 0):

It is a spatial "binding". [Node 1159592166](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1159592166) is contained in the area defined by [relation 436721](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/436721). That's all.

This information isn't directly visible in the raw data. To create such a "binding", Nominatim computes an address hierarchy based on the administrative boundary relations.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is there any way I can get this information?

Comment: Well, you need to perform the same task. I guess either by running a local Nominatim instance or by using some geocoding library specifically designed for OSM - if such a thing exists.